# Como ler várias linhas em c++ sem usar arquivo

Tags: c++

Preciso fazer um programa em c++ que leia uma entrada de várias linhas e armazene cada linha(string) num vetor.
Já tentei usar o `cin.eof()` e `fgets()` mas não funcionou.

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<string> 

using namespace std; 

int main()
{ 
    string entrada; 
    cin >> entrada; 
    while(!cin.eof())
    {
        cout << "Entrada ainda não terminou." << endl; 
        cin.ignore(); 
        getline(cin, entrada); 
        cout << entrada << endl; 
    } 

    cout << "Entrada terminou." << endl; 
    return 0; 
}
```

Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Como está o código que você tentou até agora?

Comment: [#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string entrada;

    cin >> entrada;
    while(!cin.eof()){
        cout << "Entrada ainda não terminou." << endl;
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, entrada);
        cout << entrada << endl;
    }
    cout << "Entrada terminou." << endl;

    return 0;
}]

Comment: Tem alguma maneira de especificar que meu comentário é um código? Essa é minha primeira vez tirando dúvida aqui.

Comment: Normalmente editando sua pergunta. Veja como editei. Quatro espaços na frente indicam ao Markdown que é um código.

Comment: Outra coisa: [Dê uma volta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour), para entender como o site funciona.

Comment: Vou olhar sim, obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu mudei um pouco seu código pra chegar num resultado mais dentro do que imagino que você quer fazer:

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<string> 

using namespace std; 

int main()
{ 
    string entrada; 
    getline(cin, entrada); 
    cout << entrada << endl; 

    do
    {
        cout << "Entrada ainda não terminou." << endl; 
        // cin.ignore(); 
        getline(cin, entrada); 
        cout << entrada << endl;     
    } while(entrada != "");

    cout << "Entrada terminou." << endl; 
    return 0; 
}
```

[Veja funcionando aqui](https://repl.it/IWja).

Comment: Ficou um pouco diferente do que eu imaginei funcionando no código, mas acho que assim mesmo vai funcionar perfeitamente. Obrigado!